# Many-to-Many and Eager loading query

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I am new with Laravel, I was able to query Many-to-Many relationships. Where 'template_dynamic' is the pivot of two tables 'template' and 'dynamic'.

```
// Template Model
class Template extends Eloquent
{
    protected $table = 'template';
    protected $guarded = array('template_id');
    protected $primaryKey = 'template_id';

    public function dynamic()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('dynamic', 'template_dynamic')
            ->select('*')
            ->withPivot('template_dynamic_id')
            ->orderBy('template_dynamic_html_sort', 'ASC');
    }
```

here I was able to retrieve the records

```
// Template Controller
$dynamic_fields = Template::find($rec->template_id)->dynamic;
```

what I want to do now is that pivot table has-many properties 'template_dynamic_option'. How will I query the records and combine it with $dynamic_fields variable?

```
// What I want to do is something like this. But sadly this is an invalid syntax
$dynamic_fields = $dynamic_fields->with('template_dynamic_option');
```

Any recommendation or enhancements are welcome.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

First, I am pretty sure you don't need the `select('*')` in your relationship query there.

But let's get to your actual problem ;)

To access the pivot table in Eloquent is pretty simple.

```
$dynamic_fields = Template::find($rec->template_id)->dynamic;

foreach($dynamic_fields as $dynamic){
    var_dump($dynamic->pivot)
}
```

The thing is though, by default only the keys of the pivot table are present in the object.
To change that you have to define them with `withPivot()`. Actually like you already did but not with the id.

```
public function dynamic()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('dynamic', 'template_dynamic')
        ->withPivot('template_dynamic_option')
        ->orderBy('template_dynamic_html_sort', 'ASC');
}
```

And if you have multiple additional columns use this syntax:

```
->withPivot('template_dynamic_option', 'foo', 'bar');
```